# How to hold pointers to data that holds a reference?

Tags: rust

Given the following code:

```rust
struct Data<'arg> {
    object: &'arg usize,
}
struct Holder {
    data: *const ??
}

impl Holder {
    pub fn new<'arg>(data: &Data<'arg>) -> Self {
        Self { data }
    }
}
```

How should it be completed so 'data' holds any Data with any lifetime?

If I use a `*const dyn Trait` it requires that 'arg outlives 'static. If the reference to the `dyn Trait` is passed to new, it requires that it's reference outlives 'static.

Comment: You can't give `Holder` a lifetime parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'static`, and transmute the type, but be careful to not actually expose any `'static` reference to the data as it would be unsound:

```rust
struct Holder {
    data: *const Data<'static>
}

impl Holder {
    pub fn new<'arg>(data: &Data<'arg>) -> Self {
        let data = (data as *const Data<'arg>).cast::<Data<'static>>();
        Self { data }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. The alternative is to also hold pointers instead of references in Data.

Comment: Here's the final code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6b74e122a30827b1b437371b3f7ccfe4